# keyboard shortcut to launch highlighted desktop icon

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher, 20.04

In 18.04 I could either double click on a launcher icon on the desktop, or simply highlight it and press Enter. I've gotten very used to this and in 20.04 I naturally hit Enter and then realize nothing is going to happen.

I looked in Settings, Keyboard Shortcuts and could see nothing which looks hopeful. I did a Reset All... hoping that might help but it doesn't.

Is there something I am missing, or will I just have to get unused to my old habit and forget my use of Enter for launching the highlighted desktop icon?